# Take screenshot and store in SQL VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a windows forms application and I want to store the screenshot in my SQL server database. Here is my code so far:

```
Dim bounds As Rectangle = CaptureBox.Bounds
Dim pt As Point = CaptureBox.PointToScreen(bounds.Location)
Dim bitmap As New Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height)
Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)
        g.CopyFromScreen(New Point(pt.X - CaptureBox.Location.X, pt.Y - CaptureBox.Location.Y), Point.Empty, bounds.Size)
End Using

Dim bytes() As Byte
Dim converter As New ImageConverter()

bytes = converter.ConvertTo(bitmap, GetType(Byte()))
```

I just need help inserting into `SQL`, any pointers?

Comment: INSERT INTO table(column) VALUES (bytes)

Comment: Remember that depending on the image size this can take a lot amount of data space and it is not recommended apart if small images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply make your SQL table and a column of type image. You can just insert it in as bytes.

To load the image, read the bytes from that column

```
Dim imgBytes() As Bytes = reader(0) 'contains bytes from image column
Dim memStr As New MemoryStream(imgBytes)
imageBox.Image = Image.FromStream(memStr)
```

Comment: MemoryStream implements IDisposable, always use using-block with it!